# What are the ways to calculate values in each splited sequence from the dataframe/matrix using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

What are the ways to calculate values in each splited sequence from the dataframe/matrix using python? 
or How to calculate the score of a string  from the given dataframe/matrix (score) ?
Dataframe (df) Example:

```
df
```

#output

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15
A   3   3   1   1   3   2   1   3   3   2   3   3   3   1   2
T   3   3   0   3   0   1   0   0   3   0   1   3   2   3   0
G   1   1   3   1   1   2   1   3   1   0   1   3   2   1   2
C   3   1   1   1   3   2   2   1   0   0   0   0   2   1   3


    #using jupyter notebook python 3
    seq = "ATGCGGCATTAT"
    def split_n(text, n):
        return [ text[i:i+n] for i in range(len(text)-(n-1)) ]

    # split seq by 5
    splited = split_n(seq,5)
    splited

    #output
    ['ATGCG', 'TGCGG', 'GCGGC', 'CGGCA', 'GGCAT', 'GCATT', 'CATTA', 'ATTAT']

    df.iloc[0,1]
    #output
    0

   #Something like this 
   #calculate values in each splited sequence
    vls = []
    vls = [col_val(splited,df, _ ) for _ in range(len(splited))]
    vls

    #output should give
    [11, 7, 9, 9, 11, 10, 11, 12]
```

Background:

```
#ATGCG=(A,1)+(T,2)+(G,3)+(C,4)+(G,5)
        #i.e=(3) + (3) + (3) + (1) + (1)
           =11

    #TGCGG=(T,1)+(G,2)+(C,3)+(G,4)+(G,5)
        #i.e=(3) + (1) + (1) + (1) + (1)
           =7
    #GCGGC= (G,1)+(C,2)+(G,3)+(G,4)+(C,5)
         #i.e =(1) + (1) + (3) + (1) + (3)
             =9 
 #And so on
```

Comment: What is the link between the numbers in the "background" part and the input table `df`?

Comment: Thats how the value of splited  string/sequence (ex:ATGCG=11) are calculated from the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehensions:

```
import pandas as pd
#loading translation dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("ATGCtranslate.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
#defining sequence and window for summation
seq = "ATGCGGCATTAT"
win_size = 5
#create frames of window size
seq_subl = [seq[i:i + win_size] for i in range(len(seq[:1 - win_size]))]
#sum for each frame
seq_sums = [sum(df.ix[k, i] for i, k in enumerate(sub_list)) for sub_list in seq_subl]
#output
#[11, 7, 9, 11, 4, 6, 12, 7]
```

This differs from your expected output, but if you look at the last sequence 'ATTAT', then it should give according to your sample dataframe 7, not 12.
It would be 12, if it started the number transformation at its position v8, but this is not how you calculate things in your background explanation. However, a script to achieve this version would be:

```
import pandas as pd
#loading translation dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("ATGCtranslate.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
#defining sequence and window for summation
seq = "ATGCGGCATTAT"
win_size = 5
#translate seq according to data frame
seq_transl = [df.ix[k, i] for i, k in enumerate(seq)]
#rolling sum with window size
seq_sums = [sum(seq_transl[i:i + win_size]) for i in range(len(seq_transl[:1 - win_size]))]
#output
#[11, 10, 9, 9, 11, 10, 11, 12]
```

There are probably ways to utilize pandas here directly. I will tag the keyword `pandas` in, to attract the right people.